# The lower integral of $2$ functions

Tags: calculus

Give an example of two bounded functions $f$ and $g$ on an interval $[a, b]$ such that:

The lower integral of $(f+g) \neq$ the lower integral of $(f)$ + the lower integral of $(g)$.

Comment: Did you hear about the indicator function of $\mathbb Q$ ?